# JWT authentication using OWIN pipeline getting failed for certain requests

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-web-api2, owin, jwt

I am facing a problem in which `jwt` bearer authentication using `owin` pipeline is getting failed with unauthorized access for certain requests coming from a particular region.

We have an `mvc` application that generates the token and users login into the portal using `mvc` application and on client side it is stored in cookies. Client side sends authorization header with `jwt` access token with every request to resource server (`web-api-2`). It works fine for majority of the requests but does not work for certain users which belong to a certain region.

**Token generation logic in `mvc` application**

```
[Authorize]
public class TokenController : ApiController
{
    public Token Get()
    {
        string audienceId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["as:AudienceId"];

        string symmetricKeyAsBase64 = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["as:AudienceSecret"];

        var keyByteArray = TextEncodings.Base64Url.Decode(symmetricKeyAsBase64);

        var securityKey = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SymmetricSecurityKey(keyByteArray);

        var signingCredentials = new  Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SigningCredentials(securityKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature);

        var issued = DateTimeOffset.Now.ToUniversalTime();// data.Properties.IssuedUtc;

        var expires = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddHours(1).ToUniversalTime();

        var _issuer = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["as:Issuer"];

        var claims = new List<Claim>();
        claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name));
        // TODO: add here any other claim you need

        var token = new JwtSecurityToken(_issuer, audienceId, claims, issued.UtcDateTime, expires.UtcDateTime, signingCredentials);

        var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

        var jwt = handler.WriteToken(token);

        var tokenObject = new Token
        {
            AccessToken = jwt,
            TokenType = "Bearer",
            ExpiresIn = expires.Millisecond
        };

        return tokenObject;
    }
```

**WebApiConfig.cs**

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
            config.EnableCors();
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { action = "index", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
            config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute());
}
```

**Owin Statup class**

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(WebApi.Startup))]
namespace WebApi
{
    public class Startup
    {

        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            ConfigureOAuthTokenConsumption(app);
        }

        private void ConfigureOAuthTokenConsumption(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            string issuer = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["as:Issuer"];
            string audienceId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["as:AudienceId"];
            byte[] audienceSecret = TextEncodings.Base64Url.Decode(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["as:AudienceSecret"]);

            //var secTokenProvider = new SymmetricKeyIssuerSecurityTokenProvider(issuer, audienceSecret);
            //var authOpts = new JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions
            //{
            //    AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
            //    AllowedAudiences = new[] { audienceId },
            //    IssuerSecurityTokenProviders = new IIssuerSecurityTokenProvider[]
            //       {
            //            new SymmetricKeyIssuerSecurityTokenProvider(issuer, audienceSecret)
            //       }

            //};


            // Api controllers with an [Authorize] attribute will be validated with JWT
            app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(
                new JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
                    AllowedAudiences = new[] { audienceId },
                    IssuerSecurityTokenProviders = new IIssuerSecurityTokenProvider[]
                    {
                        new SymmetricKeyIssuerSecurityTokenProvider(issuer, audienceSecret)
                    }
                });
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried troubleshooting this issue but have not found anything helpful to fix this issue. Cross verified following points:

- Client side is sending token with every request. On failure with 401 status code, it renews the access token and sends updated token to `api` but that again fails
- Public key and private key are same for both `mvc` and `web-api` applications otherwise resource server would have returned 401 status code with every request

One thing which I am not sure is that is there any network level setting or `vpn` setting which can temper/omit request headers or authorization

Comment: indeed a strange behavior. are you using any load balancer? and is there any url re-writing involved in your request?